# Quartz jobs are showing up even after deleting them. Do you know why?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am seeing the scheduler returns the same job (scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs()) even after deleting it (scheduler.deleteJob(jobExCntxt.getJobDetail().getName(), jobExCntxt.getJobDetail().getGroup())). Am I doing the right thing? I wanted to remove that job and associated threads forever. Is that possible?

```
        try {
            List<JobExecutionContext> jobExCntxts = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
            if(jobExCntxts != null){

                for(JobExecutionContext jobExCntxt: jobExCntxts){
                    if(jobExCntxt != null){
                        Date triggerTime =  DateUtils.addMinutes(jobExCntxt.getTrigger().getPreviousFireTime(), 1);
                        if(triggerTime.before(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())){
                            System.out.println("Deleting a long living job !");

                            System.out.println("Delete return = " + scheduler.deleteJob(jobExCntxt.getJobDetail().getName(), 
                                        jobExCntxt.getJobDetail().getGroup()));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What was the system.out printout btw?

Comment: Did you solve your scheduler problem? If you did, please share the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried interrupt() the job? deleteJob() only removes the job from the job store.

Comment: Thanks ! but why scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs() returning the deleted job. I will try interrupting it.

Comment: It's impossible to say based on the code snippet you posted. ie. if you have been deleting jobs with deleteJob method they might have never stopped running or perhaps you are running quartz on a cluster...